# How to generate Karnaugh maps from state transition table?

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic, circuit, karnaugh-map

I have a state transtion table that looks like this:

[image]

And the binary equation obtained from this is:

[image]

I don't have any example in my text book that solves this table with Karnaugh map. The text book just states that it can be done by inspection and I am confused about the process.

Can someone please help me covert this to Karnaugh map and solve it?

Comment: Make two 4 input maps from the first 4 columns, one for S'1 and one for S'0. The "can be solved by inspection" means that since both next state variables only have a single `1`  you can immediately read off the result without a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two tricks, basically--
1: Convert the given "don't care" Xs to 1s and 0s (see "[1]" below for first given "don't care" X)
2: Note that the outputs are never both 1 (see resultant "don't care" Xs below)
Truth Table, Completed:

```
S1 S0 A B  S'1 S'0
0  0  0 0  0   0 [1]
0  0  0 1  0   0 [1]
0  0  1 0  0   1
0  0  1 1  0   1
0  1  0 0  0   0
0  1  0 1  1   0
0  1  1 0  0   0
0  1  1 1  1   0
1  0  0 0  0   0
1  0  0 1  0   0
1  0  1 0  0   0
1  0  1 1  0   0
1  1  0 0  X   X
1  1  0 1  X   X
1  1  1 0  X   X
1  1  1 1  X   X
```

This results in the following S'1 Karnaugh Map:

```
S1S0\AB 00  01  11  10

00      0   0   0   0

10      0   0   0   0
           _______
11      X | X   X | X 
          |       |    
01      0 | 1   1 | 0
          ---------
```

This results in a minimized Sum Of Products of:

```
S'1 = SoB
```

S'0 is determined similarly.